# Why was Drax in the Kyln?

Tags: marvel, marvel-cinematic-universe, guardians-of-the-galaxy, guardians-of-the-galaxy-1, drax-the-destroyer

In *Guardians of the Galaxy*, why was Drax in the Kyln? What crime did he commit to get himself locked up in there?

Comment: Presumably Drax the Destroyer destroyed something.

Answer (score 25, accepted):

Drax's "rap sheet" indicates that he was imprisoned for 22 counts of murder and a further 5 counts of Grievous Bodily Harm, presumably while searching for those responsible for his family's murder.

[image]

[image]

Comment: Murder is always okay when you are trying to right a wrong.

Comment: @JackBNimble - The important thing is to not get caught...

Comment: Yeah, it's always okay. He's just on vacation and not in jail.

Comment: *presumably while searching for those responsible for his family's murder* - or possibly because they irked him, and he decided to remove their spines.

Comment: @Valorum: No one could catch Drax unless he wanted to be caught. His reflexes are too fast.

Comment: @JackBNimble Worked for Sandman.

Comment: [Is it ok if you don't understand the nature of your actions?](http://38.media.tumblr.com/0ff7065033d9532ad6e359e8e41f88b0/tumblr_nt11jfWgrF1sc0ffqo1_250.gif)

Comment: Who the heck were those 5 lucky people?

Comment: @DisturbedNeo - Innocent bystanders, probably

Comment: @DisturbedNeo, or better, he managed to harm Grievous five times - but only because Grievous had forgotten his four lightsabers at the cantina :-P